# Relocation of an ADF not working?

Tags: java, google-project-tango

I'm new in Tango development. I tried the latest version of **hello_area_description** of **java_basic_examples**. I found if I load an ADF which I saved before and I can never relocalize again in both learning mode on and off. 
I can not catch the 'Relocalized' log if I loaded ADF by following config.

```
config.putString(TangoConfig.KEY_STRING_AREADESCRIPTION, uuid);
```

Does anything wrong?

```
 mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new OnTangoUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose) {
            // Make sure to have atomic access to Tango data so that UI loop doesn't interfere
            // while Pose call back is updating the data.
            synchronized (mSharedLock) {
                // Check for Device wrt ADF pose, Device wrt Start of Service pose, Start of
                // Service wrt ADF pose (this pose determines if the device is relocalized or
                // not).
                if (pose.baseFrame == TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION
                        && pose.targetFrame == TangoPoseData
                        .COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE) {
                    if (pose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_VALID) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "[onPoseAvailable]mIsRelocalized = " + mIsRelocalized);

                    } else {
                        mIsRelocalized = false;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I tried to load ADF and enable learning mode. After waiting for 90 ~ 120 seconds and got the relocalized logs. but still can not get logs in disabled learning mode.

Answer (score 0):

To have a good area description, it is important to move around a bunch to gather features from many different angles. Make sure when creating an area description to move at least 5 ft back and forth.

Also loading an Area Description in Learning Mode is explicitly not a supported code path.